# In Acts 1:6, what is the significance of the particle εἰ?

Tags: greek, acts

In Acts 1:6, it is written,

> <sup>Ϛʹ</sup> Οἱ μὲν οὖν συνελθόντες ἠρώτων αὐτὸν λέγοντες· κύριε, **εἰ** ἐν τῷ χρόνῳ τούτῳ ἀποκαθιστάνεις τὴν βασιλείαν τῷ Ἰσραήλ; <sup>NA28, ©2012</sup>

What is the function/meaning of εἰ in this verse? How should it be understood and translated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote/question literally translates

> lord, if/is* in the time it, will you restore the kingdom of Israel?

*while εἰ does not mean "is", it functions similarly as "is" in this context

However, εἰ can have a slightly different meaning when it introduces an interrogative clause:

> εἰ, if: but in strong statements, approaching oaths in character, and **as the first word in an interrogative clause, it is probably a mere graphic equivalent**, first appearing second century B.C., of ἦ [and should be written εἶ], and in the former case = verily, indeed, assuredly (sometimes negative [Semitic], assuredly not, Mk. 8:12, Heb. 3:2), while in the latter it is merely a particle asking a question. [The Latin translators, however, rendered interrogative εἶ by si.] εἰ μή (nisi); but only, e.g. Lk. 4:26 f., John 15:4, Ac. 27:22, Rev. 21:27; in Mk. 6:8 probably due to a misreading of an Aramaic word = and not: εἰ δὲ μή, εἰ δὲ μήγε (Aramaism?), (alioqui, si minus, sin autem, &c.), otherwise: εἴπερ (= εἴ περ) a more emphatic εἰ, if indeed.

(Souter, A. (1917). A Pocket Lexicon to the Greek New Testament (p. 72). Oxford: Clarendon Press.)

Lexham English Bible translates it as "is"

> **Is** it at the time (LEB)

NKJV just drops the word and makes "at this time" an adverb clause

> will You at this time

The word, in this case, introduces an interrogative clause.